# Don't show complete NPM dependency list after installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I recently upgraded to the latest NPM on OSX. After running `npm install` within a package, it dumps what appears to be a complete dependency list to the terminal:

[image: Truncated dependency output]

It's similar to the output from `npm list` but with different colouring.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour? It's pretty annoying, and of no value. For our package, it's nearly 900 lines of output. Complete output [here](https://gist.github.com/stevage/9289124b8d9d935daf51).

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

Comment: I don't see any config settings there that help. `depth`, `loglevel` and `long` are in the right ballpark but don't do it.

Comment: You sure you don't have some local config file that's changing the settings? loglevel silent should get rid of this stuff, unless something is horribly wrong.

Comment: Well, sure, but switching off all output is hardly a solution.

Comment: ah you're right, it spews that crap even at  level 'error' which seems a little much. probably worth filing a bug.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11121)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `npm  ls --depth=0` for local package.
and for global dependencies `npm  -g ls --depth=0`

Comment: But I'm not running `npm ls`, I'm running `npm install`.